# Alternative Proof of $B\subseteq C$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is this proof suffcient for the statement *"$B\subseteq C$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(C)$"*?

*Proof*

*Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary. Suppose $x \in B \subseteq C$. Suppose $y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Then by definition of a power set, $y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ is $x \in y \to x \in B$. Suppose $x \in y$. Since $y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $x \in y$ it follows that $x \in B$. Since $x \in B \subseteq C$ and $x \in B$ then $x \in C$. Thus $x \in y \to x \in C$ which by definition of a power set is $\mathcal{P}(C)$.*

*Therefore we can conclude that if $B\subseteq C$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(C)$.* $\Box$

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful declaring $x$ and $y$ arbitrary at the beginning of your proof.  If they are arbitrary, then it may not be the case that $x\in{}y$.  You should pick $y$ arbitrary, then select an arbitrary $x\in{}y$ to complete the proof.

It seems a little roundabout to deal with elements of subsets.  Your proof is basically the same as if you said:

Take some arbitrary $y\in{}P(B)$, then $y\subseteq{}B\subseteq{}C$, and since $\subseteq{}$ is transitive, then $y\subseteq{}C$, which means $y\in{}P(C)$.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Yes my proof seems to have superfluous details compared to a much more succinct proof. However I was trying to do a more formal proof (putting everything in its logical form then via natural deduction deriving the conclusion) but then re-writing it in normal english. 

I'm wondering if you could show me the logical form of the original statement to be proven? I may have been mistaken and want to see how you'd express it. Can you show me the full symbolic logical form of the statement so that one can use Natural Deduction to prove the statement mechanically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you want to see the problem statement written as a logical expression in the language $\{{}\in\}{}$, then we can write $\forall{}x(x\in{}B\rightarrow{}x\in{}C)\rightarrow{}\forall{}y(y\in{}P(B)  \rightarrow{}y\in{}P(C))$.  And we can further break this down and define the power set $P(B)$ as $\forall{}y(\forall{}x(x\in{}y\rightarrow{}x\in{}B)\leftrightarrow{}(y\in{}P(B)))$ and the same for $P(C)$.

Comment: However, approaching the proof this way doesn't make it more formal.  It's actually much harder to read and a proof mimicking it would also be more difficult to follow.